# connect hadoop to neo4j

Tags: java, hadoop, neo4j

I want to import a GML file (Graphml file) from hadoop to neo4j , for that I need to do connection between hadoop and neo4j, I checked the neo4j site but I didn't find anything : https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-hadoop/
 this is what they say for the connection between hadoop and neo4j :

> In the past there were some approaches that used Hadoop to quickly
>   generate `Neo4j datastores directly. While this approach is
>   performant, it is also tightly coupled to the store-format of a
>   certain Neo4j version as it has to duplicate the functionality of
>   writing to split-up store-files. With the parallel neo4j-import tool
>   and APIs introduced in Neo4j 2.2, such a solution is no longer needed.
>   The import facilities scale across a large number of CPUs to maximize
>   import performance.

Can anyone explain me what does that mean ? 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but if you have the GraphML file you don't need a connection to hadoop, just copy the file to the Neo4j instance or serve it over the web.

GraphML import is available in Neo4j through the use of [`apoc.import.graphml` procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graphml_import_export). For example:

```
CALL apoc.import.graphml("graph.gml", {batchSize: 10000, readLabels: true, storeNodeIds: false, defaultRelationshipType:"RELATED"};
```